# Запятая перед "Сколько".

Tags: пунктуация

Посмотрите (?) сколько в России людей с фамилией Тимофеев.

Нужна или нет? И почему?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Посмотрите, сколько в России людей с фамилией Тимофеев.-запятая разделяет простые в сложноподчинённом, где средством связи является союзное слово сколько.